# Does a function has to have zero partial derivatives at its maximal/minimal point on compact domain?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

In [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319406) at page 924, toward the end of the page, it is shown that the function $F(x)$, $F: G\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ (the definition of the function is not important for this question) has a minimum at $\bar x$, and then claimed that $F$ has zero partial derivatives at $\bar x$; However, we are working on a compact domain, in particular a closed ball around $x_0 = (0,...,0)$, and we do not have to have a zero partial derivative in the case if the extremum point is not a critical point, which is not something that the author argues that it is the case.

For example, consider $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, and the region $G = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | 2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$. The at the minimal and maximal points, this function has non-zero partial derivatives.

So my question is that, firs of all, is there anything wrong with my argument, and secondly, how can the author claims that $F(x)$ has zero partial derivatives at $\bar x$ ?

Comment: I can only see page 922, but as the title suggests, I suppose that they either consider $F|_{\partial G}$ if necessary or adjust $F$ by a function that vanishes on $\partial G$ in such a way to *make* the extremum critical.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen https://www.jstor.org/tc/accept?origin=%2Fstable%2Fpdf%2F2319406.pdf%3Frefreqid%3Dexcelsior%253Afd14de06e1ca04bcba24684f002d5d3b

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Does this one work ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have edited the link with the stable version.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen By the way, the author shows that $\bar x$ is an interior point the compact domain.

Comment: no - this one forced me to accept ToC and still showed only p922. But as you meanwhile have found out that $\overline x$ is an interior point, the question has become moot, hasn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah it is. I haven't notices until reading you comment :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you like post a little answer so that we can mark as answered this question.